# DataBricks: using variable in arrays_zip function

Tags: python, databricks

May I know if we can use variable/array in the arrays_zip function ??
For example I declare and array 
array1=["col1","col2"]

then in the dataframe. I write the following :
df.withColumn("zipped",arrays_zip(array1))
then it tells me it's not a valid argument not a string or column

any one has the idea ?

Comment: anyone has the idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below, it should work:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import arrays_zip

df_zip = df.withColumn(
  "zipped", arrays_zip("column_1", "column_2")
)

df_zip.select("zipped").show(truncate=False)
```

AS per the definition:

```
pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip(*cols)[source]
```

**Collection function**: Returns a merged array of structs in which the N-th struct contains all N-th values of input arrays.

**Parameters**
cols – columns of arrays to be merged.

Collection function: Returns a merged array of structs in which the N-th struct contains all N-th values of input arrays.

Parameters
cols – columns of arrays to be merged.

Additional reference:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=arrays_zip#pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip

Hope it helps.

Comment: for some reasons. I need to put a variable to the array_zip function , instead of hard code the column name

Comment: You can do it something like this  df = spark.createDataFrame([(([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]))], ['vals1', 'vals2'])
>>> df.select(arrays_zip(df.vals1, df.vals2).alias('zipped')).collect() , it is mentioned in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=arrays_zip#pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip

Comment: that's not quite work for my case. 

as df.vals1 and df.vals2 is already hardcode

Comment: I cant think of any other ways

Answer (score 0):

using the following:

array=["col1","col2"]

df.select(arrays_zip(*[c for c in array]]).show()

Thanks